# Taking the memory address of vector elements

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

I need a cache of allocated objects that I could reuse like a free list of objects. Is anything wrong with my approach using a vector?

```
template <class T>
class Cache
{
private:
    vector<T> objects;
    vector<T *> freelist;

public:
    Cache(int max_size) : objects(max_size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i)
        {
            freelist.push_back(&objects[i]);
        }
    }

public
    T *GetFree()
    {
        T *retval = nullptr;
        if (freelist.size() > 0)
        {
            retval = freelist[freelist.size() - 1];
            freelist.pop_back();
        }
        return retval;
    }

public
    void Release(T *ptr)
    {
        freelist.push_back(ptr);
    }
};
```

Does this work?

Comment: What happens when the vector fills up and is reallocated? You'll have pointers to invalid addresses. How about using the indices?

Comment: Thanks. It is a fixed size cache. But your comment makes sense.

Comment: `if (!freelist.empty()) { retval = freelist.back(); ...` says more explicitly what you mean. (`.size()` is useful when you really care about what the size is. Otherwise using it only adds clutter and potential problems.)